# Dynamically get changed select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of the selected option (when changed) in a select list and change the text in a span next to the select list. The problem is I don't know the id of the select list. There are a lot of different select lists on the page (5-25+) and they are all created dynamically, and so I can't have the id specified in the `.change()`. Here is what I have:

**JavaScript:**

```
$("select").change(function () {
   var str = "";
   str = $("select option:selected").text();

   $(".out").text(str);
}).trigger('change');
```

(Of course this doesn't work, puts all of the select values in each span.)

**HTML:**

```
<select name="animal[]">
    <option value="dog">dog</option>
    <option value="cat">cat</option>
    <option value="bird">bird</option>
    <option value="snake">snake</option>
</select>
<span class="out"></span>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("select").change(function () {
   var txt = $(this).val();
   $(this).next('span.out').text(txt);
}).trigger('change');​
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("select").each(function(){

    var select = $(this),
        out = select.next();

    select.change(function () {
        out.text(select.val());
    });

}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery seems like, in event handlers "this" refers to source of the event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("select").change(function () { 
   var str = ""; 
   str = $(this).find(":selected").text(); 

   $(".out").text(str); 
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use jQuery's [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: It may work for adding the text to the span but won't help getting the select value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the changed element using `$(this)` within the event callback. Try changing the line

```
str = $("select option:selected").text();
```

to

```
str = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
```