# jQuery - Find out what triggered the event

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

How do we find out what triggered an event?

I want to find out if a search input was triggered using the enter key or by clicking on a button.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery/48684#48684).

Comment: Not a duplicate.  For the **DOM object** that triggered the event see the putative duplicate question (answer is `event.target.id`).  For the **USER EVENT** that triggered the event, which is what the OP is asking, see the @a'r comment below (answer is `event.type`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your binding to the search input using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) handlers as such. So just pass the event type along. For more information, pass the entire event object along:

```
$("input.Search").click(function(event) {
    doMySearch(this, "click");
}).keyup(function(event) {
    doMySearch(this, "keyup");
}); 

function doMySearch(element, eventtype) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Or you can just look at `event.type`.

Comment: @ar like I said for more information just dump the entire event object along.

Comment: So if a click was triggered keyup will be ignored??

Comment: @alex a click is a click. Its a mouseclick. It can not be triggered by keyup.