# How to get HTML element from event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In a jQuery function I am getting event on form's element click event. Now I want to get its html. How it is possible ?

**For Example:**

```
function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
    alert( $(event.target) );            // output: [object Object]
    alert( event.target );               // output: [object HTMLInputElement]
    alert( $(event.target).html() );     // output: (nothing)    
}
```

I want to get form object who's element is clicked through `event`

Thanks

Comment: check this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery

Comment: For input elements use the *val* function. html is for containers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try `event.target.outerHTML`, however I'm not sure how well supported it is across all browsers.  A more convoluted but sure to work solution would be to wrap the element in another element, then take the html of the parent element:

```
$('<div/>').html($(event.target).clone()).html();
```

Comment: Actually I want to append some hidden fields in this particular form. I am asking this question because there may be other same type of forms as well. is `event.target.outerHTML` suitable in this situation ?

Comment: So you want to find the parent form element?

$(event.target).closest('form');

Answer (score 3):

If your event is a `click` you can bind it using the `click()` method from jQuery. Use `this` to reach your element, like the code below:

```
$('#id').click(function(event){
  console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Most elegant solution I found is to simply use the properties on the event target. 
Here is an example how to detect the event source html tag. 
*This example assumes you have bound a list item click event of unordered list with CSS class name **myUnorderedList** but you want to disable the default action if an anchor tag is clicked within the list item*:

```
$('ul.myUnorderedList').on('click', 'li', function(event){ 

    console.log('tagName: '+ event.target.tagName);    //output: "a"
    console.log('localName: '+ event.target.localName);//output: "a"
    console.log('nodeName: '+ event.target.nodeName);  //output: "A"

    if(event.target.tagName == 'a')
        return; // don't do anything...

    // your code if hyperlink is not clicked
});
```