# How to open a jQuery dialog from an ImageButton inside a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, imagebutton

How can I get the ImageButton ID so that I can use it to open the jquery dialog?

By hard-typing the ImageButton ID, it works as expected. i.e:

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_linkPasswordEdit_0').click(function () {
    $('#dialog-modal2').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

However, I want to do this with all the ImageButton in the GridView and not only the first one. I have tried various ways like:

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_' + '<%# linkPasswordEdit.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    $('#dialog-modal2').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Or:

```
$('#' + '<%# ContentPlaceHolder1.GridView1.((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("linkPasswordEdit").ClientID %>').click(function () {
    $('#dialog-modal2').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

This is what the ImageButton looks like:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="linkPasswordEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnCommand="passwordEditCommand"
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' ToolTip="Click to edit password" ImageUrl="~/Images/imagesActions/password_edit.png"
    AlternateText='<%#Eval("userName")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just assign a custom CSS class (used for nothing but finding the image buttons) to the imagebutton and use the JQuery class selector to make the association.

```
$('.imageButtonFinderClass').click(function () {
    $('#dialog-modal2').dialog('open');
    return false;
});


<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="linkPasswordEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnCommand="passwordEditCommand" CssClass="imageButtonFinderClass"
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' ToolTip="Click to edit password" ImageUrl="~/Images/imagesActions/password_edit.png"
    AlternateText='<%#Eval("userName")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I hadn't thought of this possibility. Now I wonder how could I identify which link was clicked, I mean, which one is opening the dialog? I need to get the <%#Eval("id")%> as a parameter in the jquery dialog. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery

Comment: In this case, you could eval the data "Id" into a custom attribute and follow the directions in some of the answers to the post above.  Basically retrieve the value from the custom attribute using the JQuery .attr method.