# How to get ID of button user just clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

I have many buttons with ID attribute.

```
<button id="some_id1"></button>
<button id="some_id2"></button>
<button id="some_id3"></button>
<button id="some_id4"></button>
<button id="some_id5"></button>
```

Assume the user clicks on some button, and I want to alert this ID of the button the user just clicked on.

How can I do this via JavaScript or jQuery?

I want to get the ID of button user just clicked.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 37):

With pure javascript:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
        alert(this.id);
    };
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TKKBV/2/

Comment: Do you know how to do this in asp.net ?

Comment: @mutiemule ASP.NET is a server-side technology

Comment: sorry @mutiemule, I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET but there should be a way to inject js into the html that you render out similar to templates in  express-handlebars.

Answer (score 26):

You can also try this simple one-liner code. Just call the **alert** method on **onclick** attribute.

```
<button id="some_id1" onclick="alert(this.id)"></button>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Why wrap and immediately unwrap (`$(this)[0]`) when just `this.id` will do?

Comment: There's no need to jQueryify `this`. Access the DOM element's `id` property directly like in @GeckoTang's answer.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I See no difference ?