# get ID of button user just clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have checked [How to get ID of button user just clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291017/how-to-get-id-of-button-user-just-clicked) this question before asking.

I am trying to get the id of button. Below are the codes.

```
<form name="edit_posting1" id="edit_posting1" method="post" action="edit_posting_bk.php" role="form">

<center>

<input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" alt="Publish" value="Preview"/>
<input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="save" id="save" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Submit.')"  alt="Save" value="Save"/>
<?php
if($disable == true){
    echo '<input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="disable" id="disable" alt="Disable" value="Disable"/>';
}else{
    echo '<input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="enable" id="enable" alt="Enable" value="Enable"/>';
}
?>
</center>
```

**Ajax Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#edit_posting1").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var btn = $('#publish');
        //var el = 'publish';
        var el = $(btn).attr('id');
        alert(el);
    })
</script>
```

As per my understanding issue with Ajax code. Can somebody advise me on this?

Thanks

**Note:** What i want is if user click on enable/disable or publish button i get the id or name of the button.

Comment: It is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/76xycnnx/1/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I checked that but if i click on save then it is also showing publish. It should be save.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it's not working. `btn` is hardcoded to be `#publish`.

Comment: Yeah, I was testing. So, make that hard coded.

Comment: can you capture the click event on each button? click fires before submit, so you can make available whatever data you need from the click to the submit event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the id of pressed `submit button` on `form submit` you can do it by `listening` which one was clicked, save it's `id in variable`, and then `access that variable in form submit event handler`:
Check the below **snippet**

```js
 var subm = "";
 $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
   subm = e.target.id;
 });


 $("#edit_posting1").on("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var el = subm;
   alert(el);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="edit_posting1" id="edit_posting1" method="post" action="edit_posting_bk.php" role="form">

  <center>

    <input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" alt="Publish" value="Preview" />
    <input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="save" id="save" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Submit.')" alt="Save" value="Save" />
    <?php if($disable==t rue){ echo '<input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="disable" id="disable" alt="Disable" value="Disable"/>'; }else{ echo '<input class="btn btn-home" type="submit" name="enable" id="enable" alt="Enable" value="Enable"/>'; }
    ?>
  </center>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to pollute global scope instead of that use `.data()`,

```
 $("#edit_posting1").on("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var el = $(this).data('submitter');
   alert(el);
 });

 $("#publish,#save").click(function(e) {
   if (this.id == "save") {
     if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to Submit.')) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
     }
   }
   $(this).closest("#edit_posting1").data("submitter", this.id);
 });
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/76xycnnx/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.btn-home').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine This is not the submit event though. It's the click. Is that ok? This fires before submit, so you can make data from the click event available to the submit if you want.