# .Net How to get the ID of the clicked Element in a Webbrowser

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to get the HTML Id of the clicked Element in a Webbrowser.

Example: 
If i click the Google Search button it should give me the HTML ID of the clicked element (in this case a button)

How should i achieve that ?

Edit: Webbrowser = The Web browser Control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ID of button user just clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291017/how-to-get-id-of-button-user-just-clicked)

Comment: Is this using a web browser control?

Comment: Yes it is im sorry

Comment: To the left of each answer, under the up/down vote buttons is a holo check box, ticking answers gives you 2 rep points and let's everyone know your questions been solved, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's for a Web browser control, then this article explains how to do it: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32279/How-To-Tell-What-is-Clicked-in-a-WebBrowser-Contro

First off, we need to translate the mouse coordinates on the screen, into a Point object:

```
Point ScreenCoord = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
```

Now, we must create the coordinates of the browser, based off the coordinates of the screen:

```
Point BrowserCoord = webBrowser1.PointToClient(ScreenCoord);
```

Now we can use the WebBrowser documents  **GetElementFromPoint** method to retrieve the element that has been clicked:

```
HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(BrowserCoord);
```

Now, we can use this element to see what has been clicked:

```
switch (elem.TagName) { 
case "A": //! We have clicked a link 
break; 
case "IMG": //! We have clicked an image
break; 
default: //! This is anywhere else 
break; 
}
```