# How to pass data ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax

Customers.php

```
$("button[name='view']").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    document.getElementById("id01").style.display='block';
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'accountinformation.php',
        data:{'id':id},
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
});
```

and i got here the the accountinformation.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

my problem is i cant get the id it says its undefined

Comment: Try `$_REQUEST['id']`

Comment: Can you show html of your button? Have you assigned `id` for button?

Comment: same thing man :(

Comment: when you console.log(id), did it come properly?

Comment: i can get the value using that coz im using $("button[name='view']").click(function(){

Comment: @Swellar `this.id` is fine. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291034/1485183

Comment: @AmitMerchant Cool, didn't know this, thanks for the info

Comment: yes in console it shows properly

Comment: do you get anything back  if you `console.log(data)` in the ajax success callback?

Comment: Heres the button   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="view">View</button>

Comment: data:{'id':id}, Should be data:{id:id},

Comment: in ajax callback i can still get the id

Comment: @Roy doesnt work

Comment: have you checked static value if working data:{'id':100},

Comment: @jit tried to use static data same thing i can get the value at console but on the accountinformation i can't still undefined

Comment: your jquery version?

Comment: @jit 3.3.1 im using

Comment: add error on your ajax function.. try console log on that error function. in case the success never return..