# How can I know which iframe is calling the parent's function?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I have several ifrmaes that call parent's function from time to time. How can I know which frame called parent?

Comment: I hope this topic may helps you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Finding out which function is calling yours can still be done with the `arguments.callee`, but that won't work here.

In order to find out you have to tag your iframes and pass that tag along with the function call.