# In jQuery how can I retrieve the id given the class?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

To give an example suppose I have

```
<p id="name" class="editable"...
```

Later on in JavaScript I have

```
$("#editable").focusout(function(e){...
```

How can I retrieve the id of the element that has just lost the focus?

Comment: Should your selector be `.editable`?

Comment: @Esailija: Good find! I added it to the tag wiki, we should build a proper FAQ there (I think this is one of it).

Comment: @FelixKling cheers, finding all these duplicates really improves my google skills :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong selector in jQuery, must be:

```
$(".editable")
```

To alert `id` of element that lost focus you need to use `this` context as selector inside callback:

```
$(".editable").focusout(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: [`.focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".editable").focusout(function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Or, if the `.editable` element is just a wrapper and the interesting element (`input`) is a child of it, then:

```
$(".editable").focusout(function(e){
    var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/MWvAV/1/