# event target is button clicked true jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I accomplish something like this:

```
function (e) { 
if(e.("#this_button_is_clicked").true)
{//then do this}
});
```

?

**EDIT:**

```
 $("body").click
       (
         function (e) {
             if (e.target.className !== cls || e.target.click("#bUpdate")) {
               //do this
             }
         }
       );
```

I have a text box, and whenever I click somewhere else it fires on blur to that text box.But when I click to button looks like it doesn't see it as a 'body.click' so I just wanted to add it in my condition as `button.clicked.true`

Comment: Could you please explain in words what you are trying to do? This pseudo code does not make a lot of sense to me. Where does `e` come from?

Comment: Getting id of the element clicked might give some clue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery

Comment: He's already gotten the id it is `#this_button_is_clicked`

Comment: I've edited the question, cls is the name of my div where I manage my text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery event objects have a [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property:

```
if ($(e.target).is("#this_button_is_clicked"))
{
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: thank you,i tried this one, didn't work. I tried this: e.target.is("#bUpdate")

Comment: @INgeeg That's because `.is()` is a jquery method, and you need to wrap `e.target` in the jquery object in order to access it's methods.