# Angular: obtain cause of a $watch to be triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

A very short question: In Angular, is there any way whatsoever to obtain the "root cause" of a `$watch` to be triggered?

Let's say you have the following JavaScript code:

```
$scope.$watch("foo", function(value){
    // here I'd like to know if the change is triggered 
    // due to change in ngModel or through ngClick
};

$scope.changeFoo = function(){
    $scope.foo = "bar"
};
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<input ng-model="foo">
<button ng-click="changeFoo()">Change Foo > Bar</button>
```

In my `$watch` I'd like to know what caused it to be fired. In this case, was it a change in `ngModel` or was my value changed in the function of `ngClick`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think there's a way to know. Couldn't prove it though. Interesting question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that with the current implementation.

`$watch` are triggered running a function called `$apply`. That function doesn't know who triggered it.

You are going to need another perspective to fix your problem.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer, need to check if it's on the roadmap for 2.0. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, we cant know which triggers it. Check this question [how-to-get-the-dom-element-that-triggered-ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007986/how-to-get-the-dom-element-that-triggered-ng-change), maybe trying to write a custom directive to pass more info to your controller is a possible way to get trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the linked question, I'll take a look at it!