# Get ID of Element Being Clicked and Pass as Parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How does one, through jQuery, get the ID of an element that is being clicked on and then pass it as a parameter into a function? Example jQuery code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var id = this_id;
    jQuery(".lightbox a").click({param: id}, functionName);
});
```

May I note that the "param" parameter is integral to the structure of the function.

Apologies all, I am no Javascript master by any means.

Comment: That makes no sense, the document has no id, and `this_id` should probably be `this.id`, not that it would work that way either ?

Comment: What is `this_id` here? Your code example doesn't seem to be related to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the point is to pass event data to a function that expects that, as ,[**`click()`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) supports the `.click( [eventData ], handler(eventObject) )` syntax, and if so, you have to iterate the collection yourself:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".lightbox a").each(function() {
        $(this).click({param: this.id}, functionName);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

You could do this with `on()` as well:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".lightbox a").each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', {param: this.id}, functionName);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pkehj/)

Answer (score 5):

Within the click handler, you can access the element ID with `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".lightbox a").click(function(){
        functionName(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: @roasted, indeed it can be done without the anonymous function but for me the anonymous function makes it a little more flexible. Consider if you wanted to call `functionName` from elsewhere other than an event handler. You would have to set the `this` context before calling it instead of just passing an ID and if you didn't have a handle on the element, you'd have to also lookup the DOM too. In any app that is not completely trivial, I would not want the function to be dependent on the click..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this.id` inside a click event, example:

```
jQuery(".lightbox a").click(function() {
    var id = this.id;

    //pass to a function
    testFunction(id);
});

function testFunction(param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy just access to the `this` element to get the clicked element, then extract its **id** and save it into a variable like this:

```
jQuery(".lightbox a").click(function(){
  var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
  callFunction(id);
});
```

Comment: Whenever you write `$(this).attr('name')` or `$(this).prop('name')` it's usually better and easier to write `this.name`.

Comment: Ok, then I will elaborate a bit. `$(this).prop('name')` is reading the `name` property of the DOM element `this` is referring to. But then you can directly access the property and avoid the overhead of creating a jQuery object and call a method (just do `this.name`). Technically, `$(this).attr('name')` is equivalent to `this.getAttribute('name')`, but when working with DOM elements you want the updated DOM properties instead of the HTML attributes, so again, you would just use `this.name`.

Comment: @FelixKling good explanation. It's like asking someone to pass the sauce instead of just grabbing it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/pArW6/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".lightbox a").click(functionName);
});

function functionName()
{ 
  alert(this.id);   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.id` or `$(this).attr("id");`, but you might want to get a reference to `$(this)` - wrapped or not - immediately and work from a variable if you do much of anything else in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can you Use `$(this).att("id")`.

```
$(".lightbox a").click(function() {
    var ID=$(this).att("id");

    //pass to a function
    TestFunction(ID);
});

function TestFunction(P) {
    console.log(P);
}
```

Live example

http://jsbin.com/enobop/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".lightbox a").click(function (e) {

        // Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click.
        e.preventDefault();

        // 'this' here refers to the link being clicked in the current scope
        // you can check the console for the id for debug purpose
        console.log(this.id);

        // pass the id to the function
        functionName(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the event parameter that gets passed to the callback function.

```
jQuery(".lightbox a").click(function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.id);
}
```

Of course it's a mix of jQuery and pure JS.

Comment: don't worry, jquery is after all js

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have a function for an event declared with
    function(event)
and the event has a target and the id of the target is, what you want. So

```
$("SomeElement").on("click", function(e){ callanotherFunction(e.target.id) })
```

does, what you wanted