# Get id from button click jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, routes

I want to get id from button click...

**Controller:**

```
 //Get
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {

        // Get member details for the specified member id
        VasPlan vasplan = _repository.GetVasPlan(id);

        // return this member to the default view
        return View(vasplan);
    }
```

View:

```
 <a href="<%:Url.Action("Details","Employervas") %>"><img src="../../Content/Images/Subscribe now on click.png" class="btn"/></a>
```

Global.ascx:

```
   routes.MapRouteLowercase(
         "",
         "employer/details/{id}",
         new { controller = "Employervas", action = "Details", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

Here, when I click button, it will take the id from first in database..

How to generate the jquery code for this??Please help me..

Comment: no. i don't know jquery toomuch. I don't know how to put code for retrieve the id from button click..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This code prints out the id of the button that was clicked.

```
$("#button").click(function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
})
```