# How to make multiple JQuery pop up , on hyperlinks click?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, dialog, popup, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to make a popup box (with text in it) come out when i click a hyperlink. I have 5 hyperlinks in my html. Here is the code :

```
<div class="four columns">
  <h4>
    <a id="OpenDialog" href="#" >Open dialog 1</a>
  </h4>
  <img src="one.jpg" />
  <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title 1">dialog text 1</div>
</div>
<div class="four columns">
  <h4>
    <a id="OpenDialog" href="#" >Open dialog 2</a>
  </h4>
  <img src="two.jpg" />
  <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title 2">dialog text 2</div>
</div>
```

I put this in my html as well :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, height: 590, width: 1005 });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

and I also included this ready scripts :

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But the thing is that the pop up functions only in the first hyperlink.

Comment: jquery ui library is added? any error in the browser console

Comment: Use "console.log" to debug your code and you can see where the code stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use jquery parent and children to get what you want. (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjVcR/2/)

```
<script>
$("a").click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent().parent().children(".dialog").dialog({
    close: function( e, ui ) {
      $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

In this case you would have to hide the .dialog divs in the beginning.
Moreover, change the dialog container to have a class (and not an id) named "dialog". This way you will not have many divs with the same id, and your functionality will be there.

Here some references:

1. http://api.jquery.com/parent/
2. http://api.jquery.com/children/
3. [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

first add these files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

then

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#OpenDialog").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, height: 590, width: 1005 });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

reference **[jQuery dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)**

Comment: you are using multiple dialog with same id so it creating problen then do with class  <div class="four columns">
   <h4><a id="OpenDialog" href="#" >Αποστόλης Παππάς</a></h4><img src="images/pappas-apo.jpg" />
     <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="four columns">
   <h4><a id="OpenDialog" href="#" >Μαρία Παπαγιαννάκη</a></h4><img src="images/papagiannaki_maria.jpg" />
     <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
  </div>

Comment: I had some other js files in it that I didn't use. I deleted them. It now pops up only for Αποστόλης Παππάς. What should I do to make it popup for the others? Different Opendialog maybe? eg Opendialog1 , Opendialog2 etc ?