# Javascript get child nodes of a div

Tags: javascript

HTML code:

```
<div id="section">
  <div id="title" onclick="hideBody()"></div>
  <div id="body"></div>
</div>
```

How can I access the `id="body"` element using `this.`...?
EXAMPLE:
`this.parent.child[1];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Comment: what is "this"? Provide more information.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio look at the example

Comment: Since it's an id, why not just `document.getElementById('body')`? ID's cannot be duplicated...

Comment: @isherwood Without jQuery?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon There are multiple sections

Comment: You can use `var body = this.querySelector("#body")` if you can assume querySelector is supported and `this` refers to `section`

Comment: My mistake. Vote retracted.

Comment: Also Ids should always be unique in an html document (only have 1 `id=body` in the page otherwise use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.nextElementSibling).

Example:

```
function hideBody(el) {
    'use strict';
    var sibling = el.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(sibling);

    sibling.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7RYZ/).

As to answer your original question about child nodes, there is a [`childNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537445%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. For instance:

```
var children = document.getElementById('section').childNodes;
```

Relative to "`this`" (shown in the hideBody function):

```
function hideBody(el) {
    'use strict';
    var children = el.parentNode.childNodes;
    console.log(children);

    children[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure using 'this' is appropriate here, but you can certainly pass the event and grab the click target's ID:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/6k7fc/

```
<div id="title" onclick="hideBody(event)"></div>

function hideBody(event) {
    var myId = event.target.id;
    var myEl = document.getElementById(myId);
    ... do stuff with myEl ...
}
```

Comment: I have multiple IDs which are the same

Comment: Then your HTML is invalid, and you should fix that first. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get child nodes of a div, use:

```
var childNodes = parent.childNodes;
```

Or

```
var { childNodes } = parent;
```