# How to get element by ID for a dynamically generated ID in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am generating a list as below

```html
<div ng-repeat="list in fileUploadList">
    <div id="{{list}}Upload"></div>
</div>
```

Inside the controller I have to get the element by ID so I am using this line:

```js
document.getElementById($scope.fileUploadList[0] + 'Upload')
```

I logged the result to the console but it is returning `null`. What should I do?

Function in controller

```js
$scope.loadHandleImage = function () {

     console.log(document.getElementsById($scope.fileUploadList[0] + 'Upload'));
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.fileUploadList.length; i++)
            {  
                document.getElementById($scope.fileUploadList[i] + 'Upload').addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);   
            }
```

where `handleImage` is a function to be called

Comment: try maybe  `angular.element('#' + $scope.fileUploadList[0] + 'Upload');`, what is `list`? is it just a string? with spaces?

Comment: The controller should have no knowledge of your DOM. If you are calling document from within your controller you are not understanding the Angular separation of concerns design patterns.

Comment: `list` is returning a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of ids use a classname on the elements then get elements by class name - this will give you some kind of array you can then loop through and get whatever attribute you want off each element.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the problem document was not ready when you were trying to access the element use angular.element(document).ready method

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
console.log(document.getElementById($scope.fileUploadList[0] + "Upload"))
});
```

here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/hqqewnyc/

Comment: I checked using debugger. Its assiging the IDs

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
angular.element('#' + $scope.fileUploadList[0] + 'Upload').on('change', handleImage)
```

instead of `document.getElementById` and `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be (if you dont care about your list object not being in the random id)

```
<div ng-repeat="list in fileUploadList" >
  <div id="{{$index}}Upload" ></div>
</div>
```

Then in the controller get the id by

```
document.getElementById('0Upload')
document.getElementById('1Upload')
```

..etc

Comment: How would I know the exact number of elements the array is returning.

Comment: That would be the fileUploadList.length

Answer (score 0):

Not angular expert but based on my DOM experience there are ways to get ID attribute. The way i do in normal javascript is here

```
str = "";
for(tmp=0;tmp<10;tmp++)
{
    str = str + "<div id='myid" + tmp + "' onclick='idofobject(\"myid" + id + "\")'>Click Me</div>";
}
```

i created html with DIV and dynamically assign it a id like myid1 myid2 etc.  there is a function call for each div   idofobject  that takes the id

just a hint that there can be ways to get dynamic id of objects

Answer (score 0):

As each div gets dynamic ID,
so the dynamic elements should be fetched using parent child relation.
**EX**: If you add 2 button in a div dynamically fetch the first and second child of that div to get each button.

Comment: You can see in my given code I am calling them dynamically.. :)

Comment: Please see the below thread you need to get the child elements using the outer div , you should give the outside div a id and they get child for that id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500592/javascript-get-child-nodes-of-a-div