# How can I retrieve the id of element that triggered my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like below;

```
function myfunction(param1,param2,param3){
  alert(param1);
  alert(param2);
  alert(param3);
  alert(buttonid);//i want to alert mybutton here
}

$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  myfunction("hi","hello","howdy");
});
```

The function is evoked using a button click event. I want to alert the button's id in the function called. How can I do this?

Comment: a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event

Answer (score 1):

The *this* in your current function is referring to the **window** object.  You want to use the **event** object (whose *target* property will refer to the element that triggered the action).

```
function myfunction(param1,param2,param3){
  alert(param1);
  alert(param2);
  alert(param3);
  alert(event.target.id);
}
```

Also, I would suggest using the jQuery *on* listener rather than the *click* listener.  This will make the listener AJAX compatible.

```
$(document).on("click", "#mybutton", function(){
   myfunction("hi", "hello", "hey"); 
});
```

Comment: where does "event.target.id" comes from in your solution? I guess you are missing the "event" parameter in your function?  ... function (event) {  myfunction("hi", "hello", "hey", event) }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myfunction(param1,param2,param3,buttonid){
  alert(param1);
  alert(param2);
  alert(param3);
  alert(buttonid);//i want to alert mybutton here
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mybutton').click(function() {
      myfunction("hi","hello","howdy",$(this).attr('id'));
    });
})
```