# Drop down menu not work

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I'm developing an easy web application, and I'm using two js libraries: dat.gui and three.js.

My problem is the drop down menu is locked. I can't open it.

```
// gui initialization (dat.gui)
function initGui() {

    var Options = function() {
        this.tenda = 'bar';
    };

    config = new Options();
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    var subGui = gui.addFolder('Setting');
    subGui.open();

    // callbacks
    subGui.add( config, 'tenda', ['bar', 'pie', 'area']).
        onChange(
            function() {
                if (config.tenda === 'bar') { ... }
                else if (config.tenda === 'pie') { ... }
                else if (config.tenda === 'area') { ... }
            }
        );
};
```

Reading on the web, it seems to be a known issue, but in some examples, I see the drop down menus working well. I'm new to js, and I thought "maybe there is some scoping issue", so I put the initialization process inside a function that does the work. But the problem remains.

I'm working on Ubuntu/Chrome and Ubuntu/Firefox. You could check the entire code [here](https://github.com/frenkhub/chart3D/blob/master/home.html), where I use check boxes instead of a drop down menu.

Comment: For what it is worth, your code works for me on OSX/Chrome and OSX/Safari.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu/Chrome. I tried my code on Ubuntu/Firefox and the drop down menu remains locked.

Comment: This works for me in Windows8.1/Chrome

Comment: any update on this?  Experiencing it in Chrome 38.0.2125.122

Comment: are you using THREE.js?  I was using orbit controls and commented out `event.preventDefault();` in the function onMouseDown.  Problem solved.

Comment: you solution works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem. In my code, I have changed:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
```

to

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem. In my code, I listen the mouse click event. and the callback function like that:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ... //other code
}
```

I found out that the problem is "event.preventDefault();", that will prevent clicking on the drop down list, so by commenting it, my problems solved. you can also check other functions which related with mouse click event.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure preventDefault is only called for mouseEvents from the drawing canvas solved the issue for me (in the Context of Three.js and using OrbitControls and a raycaster for selecting on mouseclick)

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562933/1497139
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var tag = target.tagName;
  if (tag!='CANVAS')
    return;
  event.preventDefault();
```