# Menu will not dropdown if scenes are rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

This simple dropdown menu will drop down when clicked if scenes are not included, but will not dropdown if scenes are rendered into the screen. If any more context is needed let me know. Thanks in advance.

I have tried something mentioned in a previous post([Drop down menu not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896144/drop-down-menu-not-work/34858955)),
 which was change:

```
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
```

To:

```
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

The HTML:

```
<select style="margin-left:120px; margin-bottom:-20px; margin-top:-30px; 
padding-top:0">
<option onclick="">111</option>
<option onclick="">222</option>
</select>
```

The scene:

```
var sceneEditor = new Scene(img2, camera);
```

Comment: Definitely need more context, what does will not function mean? Which previous post? Where are the scenes? What did you try?

Comment: Edit: added scene, linked the referenced previous post, updated problem description