# Selecting element ID from class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to set a click event for a number of elements that share the same class but different IDs. However, I need to be able to get these IDs. Is there a way to do this?

```
$(".buynowlink").click(function(item) {

});
```

From what I researched; 'item' is the element being triggered. Im not sure how to get the Id of the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Comment: from speakers of my laptop, i hear people are typing answer in a hurry

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
alert(this.id);
```

See what I did there? "Try `this`"? Hehehe ... I need coffee.

Comment: It's frustrating when someone posts after you, but gets more upvotes, but yours has humor so I feel like if anything, I've let everyone down.

Comment: @BeatAlex In my defence, I seem to recall your answer was originally `$(this).id`, which is incorrect :p But I could be wrong, so many answers...

Comment: It was `$(this).id` I'll admit :P, but I was caught up in the moment of jQuery and got `$` happy. Oops haha

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` to get current element

```
$(".buynowlink").click(function(item) {
  $(this).attr('id') // This will return clicked element id
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3M77R/)

Try this:

```
$(".buynowlink").click(function(item) {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

`this.id` is all you need. You can then assign this to a variable to use later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".buynowlink").click(function(item) {
   $(item).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.attr()` function of Jquery.

```
$(".buynowlink").click(function(item) {
   var id_of_clicked_element = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to get it better:)

http://jsfiddle.net/seAy6/

```
$('.buynowlink').click(function(){
    idName = this.id;
    $('.result').html('Clicked ID : '+idName);
});
```