# Getting the td that was clicked when a tr was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, onclicklistener

Lets say I have a click event set up for all TRs, naturally each TR is filled with TDs, so when you click a TR you are also clicking a TD. Is there anyway to capture the TD (or its index) that was clicked as a result of a TR being clicked?

I thought perhaps something like this, but I'm not getting anything out of that.

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var thisEq = $(this+' td').index();
    alert("thisEq: "+thisEq);
});
```

Comment: Getting single index of `td` in clicked `tr` doesn't make any sense! If you want index of td you need to click on that td which is ultimately in `tr`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HawwX/2/)**

You can get the `td` using `event.target`

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e){
    var thisEq = $(e.target).index();
    alert("thisEq: "+thisEq);
});
```

*Note : `.index()` gives  `0 to n` values, so you would get `0` for first `td`*

Comment: +1, was typing this up as an answer before all the other bad answers distracted me and forced me to comment. This is the correct way OP

Comment: Thanks guys, that's perfect, I've never used target before, I'm going to have to remember it.

Comment: @Jeremy, it happens. VikingGoat, glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

Reverse the problem round - detect which td is clicked and detect the parent tr.

```
$('td').on('click', function(){
    var tr = $(this).parent('tr');
    alert(tr);
 });
```

You could also do this through use of a delegated event handler. This one hooks onto each tr element but you could hook it onto the body as another submitter has just proposed

```
 $('tr').on( 'click', 'td', function() {
 ...
 });
```

Comment: You've given a useless answer... If someone asks "how do I change my settings?" You've essentially answered: "change your settings."

Comment: No, I am saying it is an XY problem - you are asking how to do X when Y will give you what you want

Comment: It's not an XY problem at all, unless there are unknown motives behind what the OP is asking. My original comment was for your first answer which was essentially useless... Don't post space fillers and say "this will be filled in a second."

Comment: I gave a basic answer to the problem whilst I was improving it - there is nothing wrong with that

Comment: Your answer was, again, rephrasing the question. If someone asks "how do I change my settings?" Again, the answer they're looking for is NOT "change your settings."

Comment: He wanted to capture the tr, the td (or its index). My answer achieves both those objectives through looking at it a different way. This is not "change your settings" this is "change how you look at the problem"