# Selecting only one div of entire css class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

my goal is to show an overlay on a div when that div is hovered on. The normal div is called `.circleBase.type1` and the overlay is `circleBase.overlay`. I have multiple of these divs on my page. When I hover over one `.cirlceBase.type1`, overlays show on every `.circleBase.type1`. How do I prevent this?

Here is some code:

HTML

```
<div class="circleBase type1">
    <p class="hidetext">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <hr size="10">
    <strong class="gray hidetext">gdroel</strong>
</div>
<div class="circleBase overlay">
   <p class="date">11/12/14</p>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.overlay').hide();
    $('.date').hide();

    $(".circleBase.type1").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeIn("fast");
        $('.date').show();
        $('.hidetext').hide();
    });

    $(".overlay").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $('.date').hide();
        $('.hidetext').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Pass `event` to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and see if `event.target` can't help. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Comment: So you're wanting to simply have the overlay show on hover? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to get current element reference and do like this:

```
$(".circleBase.type1").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).next(".overlay").fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).next(".overlay").find('.date').show();
    $(this).find('.hidetext').hide();
});
```

and:

```
$(".overlay").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).find('.date').hide();
        $(this).prev(".circleBase").find('.hidetext').show();
    });
```

Comment: @williamukoh ``this`` will give you the current element reference which generated event not all with "circleBase" class

Answer (score 0):

usually when I want to target something specific you just give it an **ID**.

ID's play better in JavaScript than classes.

If you had a specific container, using the container as your starting point is a good route as well

```
$('#container').find('.something.type1').doSomething();
```

This is much more efficient for jquery, because it only searches .something.type1 inside of #container.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure exactly what you're looking to do, but it looks like you want to replace content in some kind of circle with a hover text, but with a fade. To do that you'll have to add some CSS and it would be best to change your HTML structure too.

The HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="circleContainer">
    <div class="circleBase">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <hr>
        <strong class="gray">gdroel</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
       <p class="date">11/12/14</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

so your js can look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".circleContainer").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find(".overlay")
        $(this).find('.circleBase').hide();
    });

    $(".circleContainer").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.circleBase').show();
        $(this).find(".overlay").hide();
    });
});
```

[Here's a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/0ysy3qua/1/) that includes some CSS to make it nice. Try taking it out and running it, you'll see the problems right away.