# jQuery get id of element that triggered event from nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

How do I get the id of the `".item"` element from inside the `getJSON` function?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(".item").tooltip({
        items: "div",
        content: function(callback) {

            $.getJSON('mydata.json', function(data) {

                var country = event.target.id;

                console.log(country);

            });

        }

    });

});
```

I've seen an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event), but I'm not sure how to pass the event(s) in my case.

Comment: which is the tooltip plugin used

Comment: The jQueryUI tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [content](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content) callback, `this` refers to the element whose tooltip is being invoked, so you could use `this.id` to get the `id` of the current element

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".item").tooltip({
        items: "div",
        content: function (callback) {
            var el = this;
            $.getJSON('mydata.json', function (data) {
                var country = el.id;
                console.log(country);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(".item").tooltip({
        items: "div",
        content: function(callback, this) {
                        var $obj = $(this);
            $.getJSON('mydata.json', function(data, $obj) {

                var country = event.target.id;

                console.log(country);
                console.log($obj.attr("id"));

            });

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the

> $(this)

to access the current element, then you can access its ID by using

> $(this).attr('id')

See [http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content)