# how to pass name of the <a> tag to <div> tag when its shown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my form there are 4 links when they clicked content of my `div` tag is shown using jQuery.

My question is, when link is clicked I want to pass name of that link to that `div` tag, how is it possible?

```js
            $("#adduser").click(function() {
              $("#add").toggle("slow");
            });
```

```html
<div class="box-content" id="adduser">
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Mentors</p>
    <span class="notification green">167</span>
  </a>
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Students</p>
  </a>
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Faculties</p>
  </a>
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Faculty Advisors</p>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="row-fluid sortable " id="add" style="display: none">
  <div class="box span12">
    <div class="box-header" data-original-title>

      <h2><i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i><span class="break"></span>Add new User</h2>
      <div class="box-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon white chevron-up"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-close"><i class="halflings-icon white remove"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
      <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Select file</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="file" name="file" type="file">
            <input type="submit" class="blue btn" value="Add">

          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="controls">
            <a href="">Or add single user</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by passing name of `a` to `div`

Comment: Well for a start your anchor tags don't  have the name attribute, you can't get something that doesn't exist. Please edit your question and be more clear with your question.

Comment: Where is the div you mention about??

Comment: actually i wants to pass the value to div tag portion that on which link user clicked either on mentor, faculty or student. so i can pass that name to my controller and then model

Comment: Okie,,, but you havent specified your names in the <a> tag .. isnt it ? . Add name attribute to your name tag

Comment: i will mention it. its nt an issue bt how to retrive it that tell me

Comment: So you should edit your question to " i want to pass the value of that link to a div tag". (*include the id/class of the div*) When you say "name" people will think you mean the attribute name since that's what name is..... just like a value is a value.

Comment: you should try to clarify your question with example what values you  expect to get... what could help you in general could be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event

Comment: i wants to get the value of <a> tag in my div portion.. that i wants to know which link is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed the header to print out the pressed link name.

hope that's help

```js
$(function() {
 $(".quick-button").click(function(event) {
  $("h2").text($(event.target).text());  
  $("#add").toggle("slow");
 }); 
});
```

```html
<div class="box-content" id="adduser">
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Mentors</p>
    <span class="notification green">167</span>
  </a>
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Students</p>
  </a>
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Faculties</p>
  </a>
  <a class="quick-button span2" href="#">
    <i class="icon-group"></i>
    <p>Add Faculty Advisors</p>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="row-fluid sortable " id="add" style="display: none">
  <div class="box span12">
    <div class="box-header" data-original-title>

      <h2><i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i><span class="break"></span>Add new User</h2>
      <div class="box-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon white chevron-up"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-close"><i class="halflings-icon white remove"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
      <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Select file</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="file" name="file" type="file">
            <input type="submit" class="blue btn" value="Add">

          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="controls">
            <a href="">Or add single user</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cant get it :( wants to display value that u put in alert in a div portion

Comment: I've just update the code. Please check again (instead of alert, I put it in the div header)

Comment: Is it what you are looking for? is it OK now? (the java script code was changed)

Comment: @user2302126 you haven't said what div you want the text to appear in, from all the divs in your source code do you expect us to do a lucky dip? This shows you how to get the text and how to display it, i think it's time you put some work in and worked out how to place it into "that div"

Comment: is it possible to pass that value to my controller's method as a parameter?

Comment: controller's method?? what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for this . Can you pls check ..

```js
$("a").click(function(){
     // Get Link Name Attribute
    var LinkName=$(this).attr("name");
    //Get Link Text/Value
    var LinkText=$(this).text();
    
    //Display for demo
    alert(LinkName+'\n'+LinkText);
  
    //Display LinkText in SomeDiv
    $('#SomeDiv').text(LinkText);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" name="Anchor Name">Link Text</a><hr/>

<div id="SomeDiv"></div>
```

Comment: pls run it with jquery library .. it should give you the name of that link

Comment: Your JsFiddle isn't working, it would be a good idea to display the full source code/answer in your post.

Comment: Did you select jquery 1.9.1 from the drop down . its working for me

Comment: You should have this pre-selected since this is supposed to be an example of the answer.

Comment: yes its working and its fine.. but i just dont want to display it. i wants to store that value in one variable and wants to access it in my div portion. is it possible??

Comment: am newbie in jsfiddle. this is my first exampe. i am trying to update it , but it is not reflecting. thats why i specifically gave a comment to run it with jquery library.

Comment: @user2302126 yes.. you can just create your variable with any name and store the value. 
var link_name = $(this).attr("name");

And you need to specify what you exactly need to do in that div portion . that would help others to answer. You can play around with this variable.

Comment: Since the OP doesn't have the name attribute on the anchor tags you might want to swap `.attr("name")` for `.text()` this is will get the value/text of the anchor tag.

Comment: ok fine. in a <div> portion there is a heading like add a new user instead of user i wants to display add a new mentor or add a new student as per the link clicked

Comment: @srinath I have made some changes to your answer, please check to accept/decline.

Comment: `Jenish Rabadiya ` has rejected voted to reject my edit. I'm assuming Jenish didn't look at the JS Fiddle before rejecting  since i have move your example from JS fiddle to your post and added the option of using the anchor text rather than name attribute.