# Multiple submit buttons in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 submit buttons in my jQuery mobile form, and I want to evoke different actions in my target php file. I did;

```
<form action="target.php" method="get">
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Enter keyword" name="search" id="search" value="">
    </div>
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" type="submit" name="suba">Action1</button>
            <button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" type="submit" name="subb">Action2</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I distinguish between these two submit button clicks in my target php file?

Comment: why not use id then on click of id do action?

Comment: `if(isset($_GET["suba"]) { /* Do part A */ }`... ??

Comment: just have look at this link.. to get source element which fired an event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event

Comment: @Pekka can u post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check as below

```
if(isset($_GET['suba'])){
  //button named suba is clicked
  echo "suba is cicked";
}else if(isset($_GET['subb'])){
  //button named subb is clicked
  echo "subb is cicked";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

give id's to button as action1 and action2, and id for foam as form.

```
$('#action1').click(function(){
    $('#form').prop('action', 'page1.php');
});

$('#action1').click(function(){
    $('#form').prop('action', 'page2.php');
});
```

this should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```
if(isset($_GET["suba"])){
// First Button Clicked
else if(isset($_GET["subb"])){
// Second Button Clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `isset()` function you can check which button is pressed.

```
if(isset($_GET['suba']))
    echo "suba submit button pressed";

if(isset($_GET['subb']))
    echo "subb submit button pressed";
```