# Retrieve user's image selection from website

Tags: javascript, css, html, bash, web

I am trying to make a website where the user needs to pick one image from a selection presented on the site. When the user selects a picture, i.e. clicks on it, I somehow need to retrieve the name/ID of the selected photo, and have this available on the server.

This is because I must run a bash script on my server, with the selected image ID as input.

What is the simplest way this can be achieved?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @Paulie_D My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to find the id of the element you clicked ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".some-image").click(function(event) {
    // do something with the  image id below
    console.log(event.target.id);
  });
});
```

Copied almost entirely from this stack-overflow question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)