# Update specific list <li> using ajax after pressing the button of the specific list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How to update a specific list `<li>` using ajax after the success method.

Here's the simple `<li>` structure with `<div>` containing text:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>List1</div>
    <input class="update" type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>List2</div>
    <input class="update" type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here's a simple javascript with ajax:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".update").click(function() {
    var data = "List updated";

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "update_list.php"
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
        // update the specific list
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Assuming that the data, which is a string, sends to the php file, updates the database, then sends back the string to update a specific list after click the update button of the specific list. Lets say the first list will be updated. How can I update the specific list after a click the update button of a specific list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this question: [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

What you want is to get the current clicked element's parent 'li', and then find the `div` inside it. So something like the following:

```
$(function() {
  $(".update").click(function() {
    var data = "List updated";
    var parentlistElement = $(this).parent(); // points to li

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "update_list.php"
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        // update the specific list item
        parentListElement.find('div').text(response);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Let's say the structure is like this: `<ul><li><div><input></div></li></ul>`.
How to access the `<li>` if the parent of the `<input>` is `<div>` ? @slider

Comment: @Zange-chan it would be `$(this).parent().parent()`, where `$(this)` gets the `input` element. Check out https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery it's [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector.

```
$(function() {
  $(".update").click(function() {
    let data = "List updated";
    let sibling = $(this).siblings();

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "update_list.php"
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
        sibling.text("Whatever");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/309q5852/