# id of element that fired event (this) $(this) unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of code:

```
<button id="hit">hit</button>

$('button').click(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
    $(this).append("ok");
});
```

I'm assuming that `$(this)` is necessary to refer to `$(button)`, based on [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event), which also works in the following line that works as expected (adds 'ok' to the button text). I can't figure out why `console.log(this.id);` works and the following do not:

`console.log( $(this.id) );`

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

From what I can tell, this is the opposite of what's supposed to be happening: `$(this)` seems like it should be referring to the jQuery object--I don't see how the examples that work have a (this) and a $(this) that refer to the same object. Where am I getting my understanding wrong?

Comment: `this` refers to the dom object and `$(this.id)`  is not correct, it sould be `$('#' + this.id)` (id selector start with `#`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click event handler `this` refers to the dom object, to convert it to jQuery object wrap it with `$` like `$(this)`.

And `$(this.id)` is not correct selector, which search for the tag element `hit`. Since it's an `id`  of the element it should start with `#`.

```
$('#' + this.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be more apt in your case.
 
console.log($(this).attr("id"));