# HTML and Javascript - Detecting which div box was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

If I have multiple div boxes lined up (not overlapping), how can I detect which box is clicked?

For example, here is pseudocode:

HTML:

```
<div id="box1" onClick="clicked()">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" onClick="clicked()">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3" onclick="clicked()">Box 3</div>
```

JS:

```
function clicked(){
    var first="box1";
    var second="box2";
    var third="box3";

    if (the div id of what you clicked is equal to first)
       /*do something here*/
    if (the div id of what you clicked is equal to second)
       /*do something here*/
    etc
    etc
}
```

My main problem is that I don't know how to properly write the if statement. I'm not sure how to get the div's id that you clicked in JavaScript. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById() = first)
     /*do stuff*/
```

I'm aware that I can solve this problem by having three different functions such as `clicked1()`, `clicked2()`, and `clicked3()`, but I would prefer not to have so many functions.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: `event.target.id`?

Comment: Hint: the handler can take arguments. Inside the very first argument you will find what you need.

Comment: Change `onclick="clicked()"` to `onclick="clicked(this)"`. Then, add the parameter to your function: `function clicked(e) {...`. Finally, you can get the id by doing `var myId = e.id` inside the function.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery right now, but I can learn to implement it if that's the best way to go.

Comment: Unless you cannot use jQuery in your project I recommend you to use it always! Simplifies a lot your Javascript code.

Comment: @FernandoFradegrada - That is, I'm afraid, a terrible piece of advice.

Comment: I will use Santi's method for now and I will look into jQuery too. You guys are the best, thanks again!

Comment: Just as a scale of what you know, is this pseudo code because you're learning the basics such as [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), or is this pseudo code for a different reason?

Comment: I called it pseudo code because I thought that word means "here's code that doesn't actually work because it's just for summing up the general functions". Sorry if I'm using the word wrong! 

And yes, I am learning the basics right now.

Comment: Another idea; use different event handlers for each `div`. Unless you have shared code that all boxes share (which perhaps could be refactored to a separate function), there's no reason to use the same function for all of them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Comment: You're totally right @Cait, just wanted to see how much I needed to explain in my question. If you're confused about anything in my answer, just tell me. Also, have any of the answers worked yet?

Answer (score 3):

**Pure** Javascript has a built in `target` in the `event` object. This is basically the opposite of `getElementById`, its basically `getIdByElement`(though this method doesn't exist). To access it all you need to do is edit your HTML from `onClick="clicked()"` to `onClick="clicked(event)"` and change your `clicked` function into code similar to this:

```
function clicked(event) {
  var id = event.target.id,
      first = 'box1',
      second = 'box2',
      third = 'box3';
  if(id === first) {
    ...
  } else if(id === second) {
    ...
  } else if(id === third) {
    ...
  }
}
```

To explain why this works, when a JavaScript [`event`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) is fired you get an object about it, it looks like this:
[image: mousevent picture]

This is so that you can get certain details about what happened. In this case, you wanted the target id. This works by [selecting](http://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/selectors/) all divs on the page. Also to shorten the code if you want, you can pass in [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) instead and do `this.id`. Such as:

```
function clicked(reference) { //pass in this instead of event
  let id = reference.id;
  ...
}
```

Here is an example of it in work:

```js
function clicked(event) {
  let p = document.getElementById('clicked-item')
  p.textContent = event.target.id + ' clicked';
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" onClick="clicked(event)">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" onClick="clicked(event)">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3" onclick="clicked(event)">Box 3</div>
<p id="clicked-item">none clicked</p>
```

---

It is a good idea to separate HTML and JS(though not 100% necessary). So to remove the `onClick` attribute on each element do something like this:

```
let selector = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
for(let element of selector) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    clicked(event);
  });
}
```

The code starts by getting all elements that are a `div` with [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp), though you can use other `selectors` too. Then using a `for loop` we loop through all the divs and add an `onClick` event running `clicked`.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* make this work using inline event handlers but it'd be better to move your binding code to your actual scripts. You can still use one function, just apply it to each element.

The click handler will receive an event object which gives information about the click. Part of that is the `.target` property which will give you the source of the click event i.e, the element you clicked on.

```js
function clicked(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  console.log(target.id);
}

document.querySelector('#box1').addEventListener('click', clicked);
document.querySelector('#box2').addEventListener('click', clicked);
document.querySelector('#box3').addEventListener('click', clicked);
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Box 3</div>
```

If you're hellbent on using inline bindings, the simplest way to do this would be to pass `this` into your function call. That will pass the element directly.

```js
function clicked(target) {
  console.log(target.id);
}
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box" onclick="clicked(this)">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box" onclick="clicked(this)">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box" onclick="clicked(this)">Box 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `clicked(this)` it selects the div you click on and returns that specific div's data.

```
<div id="box1" onClick="clicked(this)">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" onClick="clicked(this)">Box 2</div>
<div id="box3" onclick="clicked(this)">Box 3</div>
```

By adding the `div` as a parameter it specifies the `div` you clicked on's internal data, and adding a switch statement to trigger a specific response to each div.

```
function clicked(div) {
  if(div.id = 'box1') { 
    console.log('1');
  } else if(div.id = 'box2') {
    console.log('2');
  } else if(div.id = 'box3') {
    console.log('3');
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not an [if statement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp)? The OP specifically talked about one in his question.

Comment: You're correct, my bad. That is also another way of doing it, imo it's better.