# Using Jquery to toggle navicon for dropdown menu (clicking-off needs to work too)

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, navbar, dropdown

```
<li class="dropdown" id="dropdownquery">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i id="toggle" class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdowntitle" href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><p class="dropdowntitle" href="#">More1</p></li>
                    <li><p class="dropdowntitle" href="#">More2</p></li>
                    <li><p class="dropdowntitle" href="#">More3</p></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdowntitle" href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdowntitle" href="#">Recent News</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdowntitle" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
 </li>
```

I have my navbar set up. When I click on the above dropdown, I would like the navicon to change from the hamburger to a cross. I know that the following works for toggling when the dropdown is clicked:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
$('#toggle').toggleClass('fa fa-bars fa fa-times')
```

});

However, the navbar also allows the user to click-off the menu and the menu will minimise again. When this happens, the navicon does not change back to its original navicon. How can I make this happen? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
 if ($('#dropdownquery').hasClass('dropdown open')) {
    $('body').click(function(){
    $('#toggle').toggleClass('fa fa-bars fa fa-times')
})};
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to capture the click event anywhere on the page and the use `e.target.id` to check whether your menu was clicked. You may need to adapt this code for your needs.

You could have used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event) to fix your problem.

```
$('body').click(function(e)
{
    var targetId = e.target.id;
    if(targetId == "dropdownquery")
    {
        $('#toggle').addClass('fa fa-bars fa fa-times')
    }

    else
    {
        $('#toggle').removeClass('fa fa-bars fa fa-times')
    }
});
```