# Set onclick event to a class of elements: how to get id of the one clicked? javascript only

Tags: javascript, events

The problem:

I have 134 elements which must have an onclick event attached.
I am doing this by now, on eeeeeeevery single one of them (and they have an ondbclick event attached too!):

```
<div id="id1" class="name" onclick="functionName(this.id)"></div>
<div id="id2" class="name" onclick="functionName(this.id)"></div>
<div id="id3" class="name" onclick="functionName(this.id)"></div>
```

but read in Eloquent Javascript (chapter 14) that this is considered bad practice, since it mixes html and javascript.

So I thought I could find a way to attach the onclick event to all of them together. I searched a few hours and tried a few things, like this: (from 'How do you set a JavaScript onclick event to a class with css' here on stackoverflow)

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nameOfTheClass');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var OneElement = elements[i];
        OneElement.onclick = function() {
           //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Which got the click to work on the elements, but not my function.

My original function was receiving two values, the id and the innerHTML of the element that got clicked, and now I cannot find a way to access that information.

I tried OneElement.id and OneElement.innerHTML just to find out that it gets the id and innerHTML of the last of the elements in the document.

Any clues? Any help very much appreciated! :)

Comment: You need to pass in the event object. That will give you access to the element's properties including id and innerhtml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Comment: @GovindRai, ok, I will read about it. Thanks!

Comment: inside event handler the target element (`OneElement` in OP) is available as **`this`** with all its properties like `this.id`, `this.innerHTML`, and so on.

Comment: @MrUnity you might take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/1156518

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an event is triggered in JavaScript, it passes an event object to the callback function. Pass that into the signature and you will gain access to element's properties.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nameOfTheClass');
    
    for (const element of elements) {
        element.addEventListener("click", e => {
            console.log("element was clicked", e.target.id, e.target.innerHTML);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Another question: is it better to use this approach or the one using addEventListener?. I mean what is considered to be better practice?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Neither is wrong. If you need multiple events to be triggered on a click, for example, then you must use addEventListener. Otherwise you can stick to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="id1" class="name">first</div>
<div id="id2" class="name">second</div>
<div id="id3" class="name">third</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
  Array.from(nodes).forEach(function (node) {
    node.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      alert('you clicked' + event.target.textContent + ' with id: ' + event.target.getAttribute('id'));
      // you might also use event.target.innerHTML here
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for your answer, since I am starting on this I will prefer the next answer, it seems a little easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are two DOM apis I would recommend you use:

1. [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and `document.querySelectorAll` and
2. [`element.addEventListener('click', event => {/* ... */});`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Those are my gotos for "vanilla js" dom manipulation.

See the example below for what you wanted.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.name')).forEach(element => {
  // for each element that matches the querySelector `.name`
  element.addEventListener('click', clickEvent => {
    // call your function when the element is clicked
    // see the properties of a Dom Element here:
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element
    yourFunction(element.id, element.innerHTML);
  });
})

function yourFunction(id, innerHtml) {
  // use the values!
  console.log({id, innerHtml});
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="name">[click me] inner html 1</div>
<div id="id2" class="name">[click me] inner html 2</div>
<div id="id3" class="name">[click me] inner html 3</div>
```