# How to check which element is triggered in one event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two button that run the same script but create different parameter.

```
<input type='button' id='btn_a' value='button_a' /><br />
<input type='button' id='btn_b' value='button_b' /><br />
```

How to set the button to create parameter for each which is pressed? something like this perhaps.

```
$('#btn_a, #btn_b').on('click', function(){
     if( $('#btn_a').data('clicked', true)) {
        //Create parameter for button A
    }

    if( $('#btn_b').data('clicked', true)) {
        //Create parameter for button B
    }

    //script for sent the parameters
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **compare the `id` of the clicked `button`**.

```
this.id === "btn_a"
```

or

```
event.currentTarget.id == "btn_a"
```

i.e. use a [switch-case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to do button specific operation

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btn_a, #btn_b').on('click', function(){
        switch( this.id )
        {  
           case "btn_a":
            //Create parameter for button A
            console.log(this.id)
           break;
           case "btn_b":
            //Create parameter for button B
            console.log(this.id)
           break;
           default:
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='btn_a' value='button_a' /><br />
<input type='button' id='btn_b' value='button_b' /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn_a, #btn_b').on('click', function(e){
   alert(e.target.id);
});
```

This should work and give you the element (target) ID.