# How can I know which button called my javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Good day,

I have three buttons - let's call them myBtn1, myBtn2 and myBtn3 - doing basically the same operation (i.e. opening a div in modal mode).

I am a little bit stuck to know "who" (i.e. which button) called my javascript. Is there an easy way to know that or do I need to duplicate my javascript part ?

Sorry if the question may sound silly.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cheers

My html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
      <button id="myBtn1">Open Modal</button>
      <button id="myBtn2">Open Modal</button>
      <button id="myBtn3">Open Modal</button>        
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Some text in the Modal... </p>
      <p>Called by [myBtn1 or myBtn2 or myBtn3] </p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/modal.js"></script>
    </div> 

  </body>
</html>
```

My javascript (modal.js) :

```
/*
    modal.js    
*/

  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
```

Comment: Look into event delegation, use `addEventListener` and look at the `target` property of an event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Comment: @Xufox, sure if you know what to look for. Thanks for your indulgence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listener is passed an event object. It's target property is the element on which the event was fired.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function (e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log(event.target)
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
   <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
   <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
   <button id="button3">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Devashish, do I need to add this part to the javascript file I have?

Comment: Yes. But note that the code will add a click event listener to all the buttons in the document. If you want this to execute only when certain buttons are clicked, give those buttons a class and change the selector to `document.querySelectorAll(".button-class")`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Devashish. 

I see indeed something in the console <button id="myBtn1" class="button">...1</button>

Does it mean also that I need to modify the function btn.onclick accordingly ? Now, I am not sure how I can exploit what is given by the console.

Comment: You don't need the line `btn.onclick` and assign an event listener that way. `e.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log(event.target)
    });` is adding an event listener on every button in the document.

Comment: If it helped, please accept the answer. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target` in your event handler to determine the object that dispatched the event. This way you can easily attach one handler to the parent to process events on all of its children.

```js
document.getElementById("div").onclick = function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
  <button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
  <button id="btn3">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OP might not want the event to fire when a click happens inside the div but not on any button.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <button id="myBtn1" onclick="btnclick(this)">Open Modal</button>
 <button id="myBtn2"  onclick="btnclick(this)">Open Modal</button>
 <button id="myBtn3"  onclick="btnclick(this)">Open Modal</button>
```

And in your `javascript` function you can see:

```
function btnclick(ref){
   var id = $(ref).attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Avoid inline event attributes.

Comment: var id = $(ref).attr('id'); insetad of console.log;

Answer (score -2):

Since you have included the js using the script tag in your HTML file, all the js functionalities and events will be available.

// Get the button that opens the modal

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
```

there is a mistake in your code, you should provide a valid id.

`var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");` // this will work

now myBtn1 will initiate the onclick call

// in your modal.js

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function (e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log(event.target)
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question and should be a comment instead.