# Determine the field that called a function

Tags: javascript

Not sure exactly what to ask here, so please be patient.

I have an input field, and i need to grab the onfocusin and onfocusout events and perform some logic.

I would like to use a single common function to handle the onfocusin, and a common function to handle the onfocusout function.

So - how would i determine the ID of the input field within the functions?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="location_notes"  onfocusin="fieldFocusIn()" onfocusout="fieldFocusOut()" placeholder="Location Notes">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="additional_notes"  onfocusin="fieldFocusIn()" onfocusout="fieldFocusOut()" placeholder="Additional Notes">

function fieldFocusIn(){
// do some stuff with the calling field
}

function fieldFocusOut(){
// do some different stuff with the calling field
}
```

Comment: `onfocusin="fieldFocusIn(this)"` and then `function fieldFocusIn(element)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Comment: try passing this inside the function call. Like onFocusIn="fieldFocusIn(this)" and onFocusOut="fieldFocusOut(this)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget.id` - in order to get the event object, because you're using inline events, you need to pass the word `event` into your function calls. a.e. `onfocusin="fieldFocusIn(event)"`

In your event handlers you receive the event parameter, and look at the `currentTarget` object within that event, and at the `id` property of that object.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="location_notes"  onfocusin="fieldFocusIn(event)" onfocusout="fieldFocusOut(event)" placeholder="Location Notes">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="additional_notes"  onfocusin="fieldFocusIn(event)" onfocusout="fieldFocusOut(event)" placeholder="Additional Notes">

<script>

function fieldFocusIn(e){
console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
// do some stuff with the calling field
}

function fieldFocusOut(e){
console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
// do some different stuff with the calling field
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply pass your desired `id` as a function argument:

```
<input 
    id="location_notes"  
    onfocusin="fieldFocusIn('location_notes')" 
    onfocusout="fieldFocusOut('location_notes')"
>

function fieldFocusIn(id){
    console.log(id) // location_notes
}

function fieldFocusOut(id){
   console.log(id) // location_notes
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to repeat the id. You could simply do `onfocusin="fieldFocusIn(this.id)"` for example

Answer (score 0):

Just take the `id` from the `target` in the event:

```
function fieldFocusIn(event){
    console.log(event.target.attributes.id.value);
}

function fieldFocusOut(event){
   console.log(event.target.attributes.id.value);
}
```

Comment: right, but inline functions don't naturally pass the event object.

Comment: Yeah - as your answer notes, he'll need to modify his HTML a little - why I upvoted it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/1244884) if you find yourself attaching the same event handlers over and over again:

```js
function focusIn(callback) {
  document.querySelector('#fields').addEventListener('focusin',
    (event) => callback(event.target.id));
}

function focusOut(callback) {
  document.querySelector('#fields').addEventListener('focusout', 
    (event) => callback(event.target.id));
}

focusIn((id) => console.log(`focus in: ${id}`));
focusOut((id) => console.log(`focus out: ${id}`));
```

```html
<div id="fields">
  <input id="foo" placeholder="foo" />
  <input id="bar" placeholder="bar" />
  <input id="baz" placeholder="baz" />
  <input id="bat" placeholder="bat" />
</div>
```