# On click html table row, how do i specify each row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have code.

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="a1">
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="a3">
    <td>4d</td>
    <td>a23</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If I want to get id value of the row I clicked.

```
<script>
$('tr').click(function(){
  var a = //something values
  alert(a);
});
</script>
```

What should I put inside something?

---

For another question(this is original problem of above question), when I have below code

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4d</td>
    <td>a23</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And if I want second td value of the row I click
which script code should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Comment: (SOLVED) Thanks for the answers, found out i should use $('tbody tr') instead of just $('tr')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *this* object from which you can get the *id* attribute:

```js
$('tr').click(function(){
  var a = this.id
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="a1">
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>a2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="a3">
      <td>4d</td>
      <td>a23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To get the second *td* you can use `find()` and `eq()`

```js
$('tr').click(function(){
  var secondTD = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
  alert(secondTD);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="a1">
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>a2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="a3">
      <td>4d</td>
      <td>a23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

first question.
you may use like this

```
<script>
    $('tr').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id');
    });
</script>
```

And second question

You may use

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    alert($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the code runs after document is loaded. The second td value is in this snippet, too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('tr').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var secondTdValue = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question. You can use `this.id` to get the `id` of the row you clicked on.

```js
$('tr').click(function() {
  var a = this.id;
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="a1">
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>a2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="a3">
      <td>4d</td>
      <td>a23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, this isn't needed for your second question. To do this you can use:

`this.children[1].textContent;`

Here `this` refers to the `tr` you clicked on, and `.children` is a collection of the `td` elements. Thus targeting index `1` of this array will give you the second `td` in the row.

See working example below:

```js
$('tr').click(function() {
  var a = this.children[1].textContent;
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>a2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4d</td>
      <td>a23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```