# How to get base selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script like this:

```
var target = $('#box1, #box2, #box3, #boxn').find('.content p');
target.hover(function() {
    alert([the base element]);
})
```

I need to get the base element `#box1` or `#box2` or `#box3` etc that contains the element that has the mouse over itself.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Pass the event object, and retrieve `$(event.target).closest('[id^="box"]');`.

Comment: what do you mean with "pass the event object", I don't get it... sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Comment: @eldar No, because my event is fired on the `p` element that is child of the box

Comment: `target.hover(function(event$) {
    event$.currentTarget // <- this is what you seek.
})`

Comment: @DaFois Jquery passes the event object to the handler function, similar to events attached by native `addEventListener`, i.e. `target.hover(function(event) {...});`.

Comment: @Eldar It looks like the events are attached to the `p` elements, which are also referred by `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: @Teemu I simplified the id names but I don't have `box1` as real name... I need to get it from the script...

Comment: @Teemu sorry it should be the target not current target. `target` is the original element that owns the event.

Comment: @DaFois Then use event delegation (attach the listeners to "`#boxN`"s`), that way Eldar's comment would work.

Comment: How many `#box` is there and what's their real Id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery event handlers have a [general form](https://api.jquery.com/on/) that could handle what you're asking:

```js
// `.hover()` is a helper for handling both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`
$('#box1, #box2, #box3, #boxn').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.content p', function(event) {
    // element that is currently the focus of the bubbled event;
    // usually the same as `this`, the element on which the event was triggered
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    // element to which this handler is bound
    console.log(event.delegateTarget);
});
```

If set up this way, `.delegateTarget` would be the parent element you want.